# Can I possibly use TweenService to tween Image Transparency on Roblox Studio?

Tags: lua, roblox, tween

I am trying to use TweenService to tween ImageTransparency and BackgroundTransparency, but it isn't working, and there is no error.

I want to see what I did wrong and how to fix it. I expect that the image's ImageTransparency property changes when I use TweenService.

```
ts:Create(loadinggui.logo,TweenInfo.new(1),{ImageTransparency = 0})--not working -- no error
wait(3)
ts:Create(loadinggui.logo,TweenInfo.new(1),{ImageTransparency = 1})--not working -- no error
wait(1)
ts:Create(loadinggui,TweenInfo.new(1),{BackgroundTransparency=1})--not working -- no error
```

Comment: It seems `Create` returns a `Tween` that you have to `:Play()` for it to do anything.